# using firebreath created npapi for chrome can i call the plugin methods from the extensions and not from html loaded page

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, npapi, firebreath

I've built a simple NPAPI plugin, and registered it with Chrome. This all works; javascript in the browser is able to interact with plugin.

But i need to be able to call methods of my plugin from Chrome extensions.

Can it be done?

Comment: i guess same as javascript calling from html page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Extensions are implemented in JS and HTML, so you can embed and call a plugin from an extension just as you would from a web page.